# Query is very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tables

table1

```
epid        etid        id          EValue       reqdate
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ----------
15          1           1           498925307069 2012-01-01
185         1           2           A5973FC43CE3 2012-04-04
186         1           2           44C6A4B776A2 2012-04-05
205         1           2           7A0ED3F1DA13 2012-09-19
206         1           2           77771D65F9C4 2012-09-19
207         1           2           AD74A4AA41BD 2012-09-19
208         1           2           9595ABE5A0C8 2012-09-19
209         1           2           7611D2FB395B 2012-09-19
210         1           2           04A510D6067A 2012-09-19
211         1           2           24D43EC268F8 2012-09-19
```

table2

```
PEId        Id          EPId
----------- ----------- -----------
43          9           15
44          10          15
45          11          15
46          12          15
47          13          15
48          14          15
49          15          15
50          16          15
51          17          15
52          18          15
```

table3

```
PLId        PEId        Id          ToPayId
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
71          43          9           1
72          43          9           2
73          44          10          1
74          44          10          2
75          45          11          1
76          45          11          2
77          46          12          1
78          46          12          2
79          47          13          1
80          47          13          2
```

I want to get one id whose count is less than 8 in table 3 and order by peid in table 2,

I have written query

```
SELECT Top 1  ToPayId FROM 
(
    SELECT Count(pl.ToPayId) C, pl.ToPayId 
    FROM table3 pl 
    INNER JOIN table2 pe ON pl.peid = pe.peid 
    INNER JOIN table1 e ON pe.epid = e.epid
    WHERE e.EtId=1 GROUP BY pl.ToPayId 
) As T 
INNER JOIN table2 p ON T.ToPayId= p.Id 
WHERE C < 8 ORDER BY p.PEId ASC
```

This query executes more than 1000 times in stored procedure depends on the entries in user-defined-table-type using while condition.

But it is very slow as we have millions of entries in each table.

Can anyone suggest better query regarding above?

Comment: Are there any indexes? Perhaps you could show us DDL for the tables.

Comment: For future reference, "lakh" is a unit meaning 100,000.

Comment: Yes, I have created nonclustured index on etid(table1), topayid,peid(table3)

Comment: If you use the show (estimated) execution plan options, you can see what is slowing your query down and take steps to alleviate it.

Comment: Why do you make inner join with the results from the subquery? is that necessary?

Comment: @Leandro Barreto : Yes, it is necessary to check the value of e.EtId=1/2/3 from table 1.

Comment: I meant in the `INNER JOIN table2 p ON T.ToPayId= p.Id` statement. If you make the join just for the order, you could bring the value from the subquery

Comment: Yeah, I need the id in the order depending on there entries in table2.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try with the having clause to get rid of the from select

```
select table2.id as due
      from table3 inner join table2 on table2.PEId=table3.PEId...
      group by ...
      having count(due) <8
      order by ...
```

-> you have a redundant Id column in table3 : seems pretty useless as the couple PEId and Id appears unique so remove it and reduce the size of table 3 by 25% hence improving performance of db

Comment: Table structure is proper as per the business logic, and it can not be altered now.
And I am trying your suggested query(having) but it does not contain table1.
table1 is required to check etid value.

Comment: this was an example, if i do your job i might as well get your salary !? anyway the having is the proper way to go; NB: redondancy is costly and there aren't any business logic that i know of that advocate for waste of resources

Comment: my pleasure although let us know how faster it is & accept answer thks

Comment: Result must be in order (table1.peid), if I use order by , I need to include that column i select list.

Issue is I'm storing the value variable.
Please see my old query SELECT Top 1  ToPayId.

what would be the solution.

Comment: table1.epid = table2.EPID ? if so why would you need table1 in the query ? if not fill the example given with what is missing in your case

Comment: Yes, it table 1 is important in the query

Answer (score 0):

Will.. since you did not provide enough sample data and  I am not sure what exactly  your business logic is. So that I can just modify the code in blind.

```
SELECT ToPayId 
FROM (

    SELECT TOP 1 Count(pl.ToPayId) C, pl.ToPayId, pe.PEId
    FROM table3 as pl 
        INNER JOIN table2 as pe ON pl.peid = pe.peid AND pl.ToPayId = pe.Id
        INNER JOIN table1 e ON pe.epid = e.epid
    WHERE e.EtId=1
    GROUP BY pl.ToPayId, pe.PEId 
    HAVING Count(pl.ToPayId) < 8
    ORDER BY pe.PEId ASC    

) AS T
```

Comment: can't find why, but query returns nothing. and as you include PEId in group by , it will return first record from  Db(all the rows if not top 1)

Comment: I've tried your code and it returns nothing as well. I think It may more helpful if you can explain the business logic more clearly and provide more sample data.